# How do you create a list of dictionaries from a .tsv file in Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have a .tsv file that looks like this:

```
date        fruit weight  unit
2021-10-07  avocado 150  g
2021-10-17  mango   300  g
2021-10-29  banana  90   g
2021-11-28  avocado 100  g
2021-12-02  avocado 120  g
2021-12-04  orange  92   g
```

I want to turn it into a list of dictionaries to use in Python and I am using this code:

import pandas as pd
import os

```
def load_tsv_file(file_name):
    file_location = f"data/{file_name}"

    if not os.path.isfile(file_location):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"The file '{file_location}' does not exist.")

    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(file_location, sep='\t')
        return data
    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError as e:
        raise ValueError(f"The file '{file_location}' is empty.") from e
    except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
        raise ValueError(f"Error parsing the TSV file '{file_location}'. Please check the file format.") from e


yield_data = load_tsv_file('fruit_weight.tsv')

fruit_data_dict = fruit_data.to_dict('records')

for item in fruit_data_dict:
    print(item)
```

Which results in this:

```
{'date    fruit    weight  unit': '2021-10-07  avocado   150 g'}
{'date    fruit    weight  unit': '2021-10-17  mango     300  g'}
{'date    fruit    weight  unit': '2021-10-29  banana    90 g'}
{'date    fruit    weight  unit': '2021-11-28  avocado   100  g'}
{'date    fruit    weight  unit': '2021-12-02  avocado   120  g'}
{'date    fruit    weight  unit': '2021-12-04  brocolli  92  g'}
```

But what I want is something like:

```
{'date': '2021-10-07', 'fruit':  'avocado', 'weight': '150', 'unit': g'},
{'date': '2021-10-17', 'fruit':  'mango', 'weight': '300', 'unit': 'g'}... etc
```

What am I doing wrong, or how can I do this? Everything I found online was to change csv into lists of dictionaries but I cannot find anything about tsv files.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something is wrong with your dataset.
You can use a regex to correctly parse the lines. If you change the data read from pandas in:

```py
data = pd.read_csv(file_location, sep="\s+")
```

Your code ends up with

```
{'date': '2021-10-07', 'fruit': 'avocado', 'weight': 150, 'unit': 'g'}
{'date': '2021-10-17', 'fruit': 'mango', 'weight': 300, 'unit': 'g'}
{'date': '2021-10-29', 'fruit': 'banana', 'weight': 90, 'unit': 'g'}
{'date': '2021-11-28', 'fruit': 'avocado', 'weight': 100, 'unit': 'g'}
{'date': '2021-12-02', 'fruit': 'avocado', 'weight': 120, 'unit': 'g'}
{'date': '2021-12-04', 'fruit': 'orange', 'weight': 92, 'unit': 'g'}
```